# Android onScrollChanged for Scrollview fired multiple times

Tags: android, event-handling, scrollview

I want to keep track of the ScrollY on a Scrollview (no, I can't use a grid or a list)

I am using the ViewTreeObserver with an onScrollChanges Listener to it. However, it gets fired multiple times. Even worse: when it gets called 3 of 4 times, the scrollY of the scrollview is 0 and 1 time I get the correct amount. However, it's not like every 4th call is correct, the moment when the correct value is fired is random, and I need to be able to listen to the scrollposition 0.

Here is the Code I use to observer my Scrollview:

```
mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
           Log.d("StupidScrollView", "Scroll positionY: " + mScrollView.getScrollY());
        }
    });
```

Sample output:

```
 D/StupidScrollView﹕ Scroll positionY: 0
 D/StupidScrollView﹕ Scroll positionY: 0
 D/StupidScrollView﹕ Scroll positionY: 0
 D/StupidScrollView﹕ Scroll positionY: 77
```

I have to mention, I am in a ViewPager and my fragments contain a Scrollview which needs to be observed. It somehow sounds like some issue related to that.

Comment: I am facing the exact same situation, in my custom view I have an ViewTreeObserver, and I need to check getY() value and just like your case, every 2nd or 3rd values is right. Can you guide me here please? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see your problem, i have had a lot of trouble with scrollviews myself.. Here is my solution to get the scrollvalue in a scrollview (I added a System.out for you).

First Create a custom class that extends ScrollView, and create a listener that has the method onScrollChanged as here:

```
public class ProductDetailScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
        void onScrollChanged(ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    private OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mOnScrollChangedListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedListener != null) {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }

    public ProductDetailHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ProductDetailHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ProductDetailHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Then i create a variable (in the activity) mOnScrollChangedListener, and set it as the listener for mScrollView:

```
private ProductDetailScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener = new ProductDetailScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    public void onScrollChanged(ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

        System.out.println("Scrolled: " + t);

        //Parallax Effect on scroll
        if (t > 0) {
            final float newY = (t / 4.0f) * -1.0f;
            mProductImageContainer.setY(newY);
        } else {
            mProductImageContainer.setY(0.0f);
        }
    }
};
```

The "t" value in my case is how much the scroll have changed vertically, the "l" is the horizontal scroll, and the "oldl" & "oldt" is the old value of t & l so if you need to know that it's scrolled up or down you can use if(oldt > t) etc..

And you set the listener in your scrollview like this:

```
mScrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Answer, but the Default Scrollview has no OnScrollChangedListener.

From what package do you import Scrollview? do you maybe have a lib or implemented something on your own? As i can see ProductDetailScrollView is a custom Class so i guess your missing this.

Comment: Hi Angelo, yeah that's right. Iam using a custom class called productDetailScrollView. I thought the standard one would have it too, but looking at it now i see i miss some things in my answer.. I will update my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, isn't exactly the Solution i went after but pointed me into the right direction!

Comment: @Angelo I am facing the exact same situation, in my custom view 
I have an ViewTreeObserver, and I need to check getY() value and just like your case, every 2nd or 3rd values is right. Can you guide me here ? 
Thanks.

Comment: facing the same. @ShahrozKhan91 have you found a solution?

Comment: @maysi not really, i just figured out how to intelligently differentiate wrong values from right ones.

Comment: @ShahrozKhan91 can you post your solution here? (I choosed listview for my purposes, because I didn't find a solution)

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. Adding an onScrollChangedListener via the ViewTree would give me the correct scroll values mixed in with a bunch of other, seemingly unrelated values. Subclassing the ScrollView and overriding the onScrollChanged method would result in only firing off the correct scroll values!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I replaced my `ScrollView` with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`.

Then implemented `NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener`.

Attached the Listener to my `NestedScrollView`.

And now I'm detecting scroll changes. :)